# Jquery if and else if statement on validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

Hello I have been trying to make this form work with no luck, So in submit if the textarea is empty and any of the radio button are not being selected trow a message for both, if textarea has text but a radio is not being selected trow a second message, if radio button is being selected but textarea is empty display a third message and last if both textarea has text and a radio button is being selected display a success message.

This is my html:

```
                <div id="main" role="main">

                <form action="?q=dt-index" method="post" name="subscribeForm" id="myform">

                    <div id="comment_holder" class="input_holder" style="position: relative;">
                        <textarea rows="6" cols="30" placeholder="Please enter text" name="comment" class="inp"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cbox">
                        <input type="radio" name="smile_selected" value="Awesome" id="yummy1" />
                            <label for="yummy1" class="yummy">Awesome</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="smile_selected" value="Good" id="cool1" />
                            <label for="cool1" class="cool">Good</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="smile_selected" value="Okay" id="ok1" />
                            <label for="ok1" class="ok_smile">Okay</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="smile_selected" value="Yuck" id="yuck1" />
                            <label for="yuck1" class="yuck">Yuck</label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="loading_button">
                        <button type="submit" class="default">Send</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

                <div id="errors"></div> <!-- Error container -->

            </div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
                $(document).ready(function() {


            /* on submitting my form */
                $( '#myform' ).submit(function() {

            /*          if Textarea is empty and redio button are not checked display message error for both */
                        if($('#myform textarea').val()=="")
                        {
                             if (!$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
                                 $('#errors').empty().text('Please enter your message and select a radio'); 
                                return false;
                             }  
                        }

            /*          else if Textarea is empty display message error */
                        else if($('#myform textarea').val()=="") {  
                            $('#errors').empty().text('Please enter your message');
                            return false;
                    }

            /*          if radio button is not being selected display message error */
                        if (!$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
                            $('#errors').empty().text('Please select a radio');
                            return false;
                    }

            /*          Everthing is good display success message and add SENDING class to submit button */
                        else {
                            $('#myform :submit').addClass('sending').html('Sending message...');
                            $('#errors').empty().text('All Good :D');
                        }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement logic is kind of redundant, and it allowed only a radio button to selected, because you forgot to add an "else" before the 3rd "if". But here is a better way to do it, that is also expandable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        /* on submitting my form */
            $( '#myform' ).submit(function() {

               var errors = [];

        /*     else if Textarea is empty display message error */
               if($('#myform textarea').val()=="") {  
                    errors[errors.length] = 'enter your message';
                }

        /*      if radio button is not being selected display message error */
                if (!$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
                   errors[errors.length] = 'select a radio';
                }

                if(errors.length > 0){
                    var errMsg = "Please  "

                    for(e = 0; e < errors.length-1; e++){
                        errMsg += errors[e]+", ";
                    }

                     errMsg = errMsg.substr(0, errMsg.length -2)+" and "+errors[errors.length-1]+".";
                     $('#errors').empty().text(errMsg);
                     return false;
                }

        /*          Everthing is good display success message and add SENDING class to submit button */
                    else {
                        $('#myform :submit').addClass('sending').html('Sending message...');
                        $('#errors').empty().text('All Good :D');
                    }

            });
        });​
```

Heres a link to show it works: http://jsfiddle.net/66CHS/

Comment: Thank you Greg for sharing your knowledge, after using your script for some reason if the form is being submitted without any errors,  I  am able to post the data to the next screen, but if the user clicks the submit button and a message erros is being displayed and after clearing the errors the form is not posting anything, any ideas? Thank you once again.

Comment: Is the form not submitting or is the data not being posted (but the form is still submitting)? If it is not submitting, possibly try adding "return true" after the success message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your `if` condition:

it currently goes like:

```
if($('#myform textarea').val()=="")
{
    .... 
}
else if($('#myform textarea').val()=="") {  
    ....
}
```

You have the same condition in `if` as well as `else if` - which means the `else if` will NEVER get triggered.

It should be like:

```
if($('#myform textarea').val()=="" && !$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
  // no text and no radio
}
else if($('#myform textarea').val()=="") {
  // no text
}
else if(!$(":radio:checked").attr('checked')) {
  // no radio
}
else {
  // all good
}
```